# How to parse a text file containing multiple lines of data and organized by numerical values and then convert to JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, text

I need to parse a text file with the following format and convert it to a Hash which will be converted to JSON.

The text file has this format:

```
HD040008000415350110XXXXXXXXXX0208XXXXXXXX0302EN0403USA0502EN0604000107014
EM04000800030010112TME001205IQ50232Blue Point Coastal Cuisine. INC.06145655th Avenue0805921010909SAN DIEGO1008Downtown1102CA1203USA
```

Every line is a group of segments which work with a Key value format.  For example, the second line would be:

- `EM` is key
- `04` is the length of the value including blank spaces
- `0008` is the value

Breaking it up, it would look like this `EM 04 0008`. The next segment keys are numerical and start with `00` and then increment until the end of the line which would then start all over again.  I would need to iterate through every single line in a text file.

I need to be able to convert this into a Ruby hash which in turn would be converted to JSON in an API response.

The current format would be:

```
EM0400080003001
```

It would need to get parsed into:

```
{"EM" => 0008, "00" => "001"}
```

Comment: Could you provide a couple of lines (3-4) of the text file and the exact output (in json or hash) that you're looking for? It's slightly unclear still as there's a lot of things behind EM0400080003001 (unless they're ignored). Also unsure if EM can be a digit too or not, etc.

Comment: EM0400080003001 is just an example of the format. The complete string is what needs to get parsed into a Ruby hash.

Comment: Each line can only start with letters. Like in the two lines provided the are HD and EM but it could be LS, GH, MN etc.

Comment: Here is another example of a txt file: 

CR0480280012TME001205IQ501075.463620214COMUNICACIONES3061330670403001050810022012060100701109046280100101706201306231611--1111111-1-1124010
CO0480280012TME001205IQ501060004950201003010040100501006010070100801009010100101106062013141311111111111-1
CN0430850012CCR041221JS40108010820140205BANCO
CI0180004802802100074648028

Comment: Put the additional example in the body of the question where you would have added it initially. And don't use "Edit" or "Update".

Comment: When asking we expect to see evidence of your effort. Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages, and "[mcve]". Currently it looks like you want us to write the code for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very common type of encoding called [Type-Length-Value](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type-length-value) (or Tag-Length-Value), for reasons I suppose are obvious. As with many such tasks in Ruby, [`String#unpack`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-unpack) is a good fit:

```
def decode(data)
  return {} if data.empty?
  key, len, rest = data.unpack("a2 a2 a*")
  val = rest.slice!(0, len.to_i)
  { key => val }.merge(decode(rest))
end

p decode("HD040008000415350110XXXXXXXXXX0208XXXXXXXX0302EN0403USA0502EN0604000107014")
# => {"HD"=>"0008", "00"=>"1535", "01"=>"XXXXXXXXXX", "02"=>"XXXXXXXX", "03"=>"EN", "04"=>"USA", "05"=>"EN", "06"=>"0001", "07"=>"4"}

p decode("EM04000800030010112TME001205IQ50232Blue Point Coastal Cuisine. INC.0614565 5th Avenue0805921010909SAN DIEGO1008Downtown1102CA1203USA")
# => {"EM"=>"0008", "00"=>"001", "01"=>"TME001205IQ5", "02"=>"Blue Point Coastal Cuisine. INC.", "06"=>"565 5th Avenue", "08"=>"92101", "09"=>"SAN DIEGO", "10"=>"Downtown", "11"=>"CA", "12"=>"USA"}
```

If you want to read an entire file and return a JSON array of objects, something like this would suffice:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby -n
BEGIN {
  require "json"
  def decode(data)
    # ...
  end
  arr = []
}

arr << decode($_.chomp)

END { puts arr.to_json }
```

Then (supposing the script is called `script.rb` and is executable:

```sh
$ cat data.txt | ./script.rb > out.json
```

Comment: Thats awesome! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming 2 chars for the key and 2 digits for the length:

```
line = "EM04000800030010112TME001205IQ50232Blue Point Coastal Cuisine. INC.06145655th Avenue0805921010909SAN DIEGO1008Downtown1102CA1203USA"



hsh = {}
arr = line.chars
until arr.empty?
  key = arr.shift(2).join
  length = arr.shift(2).join.to_i
  value = arr.shift(length).join
  hsh[key] = value
end
hsh

 => {"EM"=>"0008", "00"=>"001", "01"=>"TME001205IQ5", "02"=>"Blue Point Coastal Cuisine. INC.", "06"=>"5655th Avenue0", "80"=>"21010909SAN DIEGO1008Downtown1102CA1203USA"}
```

Results are looking kinda funky though.

EDIT - to step through the file you need to open it as follows:

```
File.open(filename).each_line do |line|
  do stuff with line here
end
```

Comment: Wow, this could be it. I tried it an like you said, it's kinda funky but it's a step in the right direction. I would need to be able to do this for every single line. What would be the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: `"06"=>"5655th Avenue0"` is wrong and it throws everything off after that. I believe it should be `565 5th Avenue` or `56 55th Avenue`. Hopefully just a problem from copy and paste. To process the file you just need to read it line by line. I will edit my answer to include that.

Comment: Yes, you are correct about the results of 06. Thanks for your help. It's a step in the right direction.